# The device BACK key not working and all other key events not responding either

Tags: android, kotlin, onbackpressed, programmatically-created, google-input-tools

The UI of my app is totally built with code. It's an **EMPTY ACTIVITY** with the **activity_main.xml** deleted, and utilizes the following style:

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashbg</item>
</style>
```

The basic activity looks like this, with **mainView** *(global variable)* acting as the root view:

```
class MyApp: AppCompatActivity(), View.OnTouchListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mainView = FrameLayout(this).apply {
            layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }

        setContentView(mainView)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        println("onBackPressed")        
        super.onBackPressed()        
    }

    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        println("dispatchKeyEvent")
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        println("onKeyDown")
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }

    override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        println("onKeyUp")
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    }

}
```

It should also be noted that the app has been migrated to **AndroidX** and is thus utilizing these libraries:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
```

The app works as expected except for the key-event methods. I'm trying to intercept the **onBackPressed** event, but nothing seems to be working. None of the events, not **onKeyDown, onKeyUp, onBackPressed,** or **dispatchKeyEvent** are responding. The console does not print any of the *println* outputs but instead, I get these whenever I press the phone's physical **BACK** key:

```
2019-11-14 03:57:44.541 16056-16056/? I/GoogleInputMethod: onKeyDown() : keyCode = 4, event = KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=158, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=280842030, downTime=280842030, deviceId=5, source=0x101 }

2019-11-14 03:57:44.590 1434-1540/? D/BaseMiuiPhoneWindowManager: keyCode:4 down:false eventTime:280842082 downTime:280842030 policyFlags:22000002 deviceId:5 isScreenOn:true keyguardActive:false repeatCount:0
```

Is there some configuration or setting that I might have missed?

TIA.

---

**EDIT:** *I should also add that this issue occurs when the keyboard is visible. Pressing the **BACK** key dismisses the keyboard but does not trigger the key events.*

Comment: Replace mainView with xml and try again

Comment: I've already tried that with a fresh project. I started another Android Studio template project, added a bunch of **EditText** controls, and added all the key-event overrides. Still nothing. I've also tested on a Samsung Galaxy phone running Android 5.0 and a Xiaomi Redmi phone running Android 7.1. Both the devices make use of Google keyboards, so I even tested with the OEM keyboard on the Samsung Galaxy. But still nothing. I must be doing something wrong. Are you able to get it to work at all?

Answer (score 1):

Use this for back press key

```
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

for device back button try using

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // your code
    return true;
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

Comment: This is for the physical back button.